# How to write a filtering function in Python

Tags: python, filter

I have a list of football matches in the following format:

```
# HomeTeam, AwayTeam, HomeScore, AwayScore, HomeShots, AwayShots
[['Bayer 04', 'Werder Bremen', 2, 2, 21, 10]
 ['Paderborn', 'RB Leipzig', 2, 3, 8, 18]
 ['Koln', 'Augsburg', 1, 1, 13, 11]]
```

Suppose I want to extract only those matches, which meet some criterias, for example:

- HomeTeam is 'Bayer 04' and HomeShots + AwayShots > 25
- AwayTeam is one of: 'RB Leipzig' or 'Koln'
- AwayGoals > HomeGoals

While filtering a list by a single criteria is straigtforward, for example extract the matches with more than 3 goals scored:

```
def moreThan3Goals(matches):
        result = []
        [result.append(match) for match in matches if match[2] + match[3] > 3]
        return result
```

It is not clear how to write a function which takes an arbitrary number of conditions and extract those matches which meet all the criterias.

Comment: There is a [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function in Python

Comment: You can just keep chaining conditions with `and` but it's going to get ugly. You'd be better off getting your data into a Pandas DataFrame and using the many built in filtering operations it provides.

Comment: Toby Petty, I considered using `and` though I don't understand how to do it when the amount of conditions is not known in advance and in which format the conditions must be passed to the function.

Comment: Your function can take a callback function to allow dynamic filtering, just like the built-in `filter()` function does.

Comment: RaySteam, I'm aware of `filter()` however the question is how to use it in a particular case.

Comment: First decide how you want to represent each condition - maybe a tuple `(index,value`)? That would let you loop over index,value pairs, or you could use operator.itemgetter with the indices to extract values from each *row*(?) to compare with the condition values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using `namedtuple` to make the functions readable.

```
from collections import namedtuple

# Convert raw data to list of named tuples.
col_names = ['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'HomeScore', 'AwayScore', 'HomeShots', 'AwayShots']
Match = namedtuple('Match', col_names)
raw_data = [
    ['Bayer 04', 'Werder Bremen', 2, 2, 21, 10],
    ['Paderborn', 'RB Leipzig', 2, 3, 8, 18],
    ['Koln', 'Augsburg', 1, 1, 13, 11]
]
data = [Match(*m) for m in raw_data]
>>> data
[Match(HomeTeam='Bayer 04', AwayTeam='Werder Bremen', HomeScore=2, AwayScore=2, HomeShots=21, AwayShots=10),
 Match(HomeTeam='Paderborn', AwayTeam='RB Leipzig', HomeScore=2, AwayScore=3, HomeShots=8, AwayShots=18),
 Match(HomeTeam='Koln', AwayTeam='Augsburg', HomeScore=1, AwayScore=1, HomeShots=13, AwayShots=11)]
```

Then create your arbitrary rules using lambda functions:

```
rule_1 = lambda m: m.HomeTeam == 'Bayer 04' and (m.HomeShots + m.AwayShots) > 25
rule_2 = lambda m: m.AwayTeam in {'RB Leipzig', 'Koln'}
rule_3 = lambda m: m.AwayScore > m.HomeScore
```

Now you can use a conditional list comprehension to match all the rules, converting the named tuple back to a list:

```
[list(m) for m in data 
 if all([rule_1(m), rule_2(m), rule_3(m)])]
```

Or by creating groups of rules:

```
rule_set_1 = [rule_1, rule_2, rule_3]
[list(m) for m in data 
 if all([rule(m) for rule in rule_set_1])]
```

Comment: So basically any rule should be prepared in advance? Isn't it possible to create new rules when calling the filtering function? Should I pass a lambda describing the rule when calling the filtering function?

Comment: You can create the rules either in advance or on the fly using an interactive interpreter such as IPython or a Jupyter Notebook.  Allowing a user to create rules on the fly is really too broad of a question.